# Android gradle plugin. How automaticly exclude duplicate transitive dependencies

Tags: android, gradle

After update to android build tools plugin to 0.14.1 if found my build is crashed by duplicate classes while dexing. After some investigation i've found it to different commons-io jars in libraryList.txt.

One 2.4 what i added as dependency and another 1.3 from robospice. After explicit excluding 1.3 build was successful. However

```
+--- com.octo.android.robospice:robospice:1.4.14
|    \--- com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-cache:1.4.14
|         +--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2
|         \--- org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2
|              \--- commons-io:commons-io:1.3.2 -> 2.4
```

Should not gradle replace it? **commons-io:commons-io:1.3.2 -> 2.4** Am i wrong expecting this behavior by default or it just a bug in android build tools?

Comment: Did you notice the two commons-io dep has different groupid? That's why the classes added twice, gradle cannot know those are the same deps.

Comment: @WonderCsabo yes 1.3.2 and 2.4 have different groupids. But
 \--- org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2
 \--- commons-io:commons-io:1.3.2 -> 2.4

according this, gradle smart enough. Or am i wrong interpreting this ?

Comment: This whole dep tree is messed. It say `org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2` has `commons-io:commons-io:1.3.2` dependency which cannot happen. Can you post your build.gradle or an example project?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/kivsiak/95371ab4fddcb811eedd

However this deptree is straightforward and there no confusing replacement.

And there my production build.gradle https://gist.github.com/kivsiak/2364da471ee9be23f544 there replacement declared. I think i should dig further. May be some plugin. Cause same build tools and gradlewrapper versions are used.

Comment: I just [ran](https://gist.github.com/WonderCsabo/443ce43edfc66fc561ef) `gradle dependencies` with your build.gradle. As you can see, there are two `commons-io` deps: `org.apache.commons:commons-io` and `commons-io:commons-io`.

Comment: This may happen because the Android platform itself contains `commons-io:commons-io`? I know there was some problems with `commons-logging` like this.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a dependency resolution issue per say. If the robospice library includes a copy of commons-io v1.3.2 inside its jar, Gradle is not going to automatically strip it out for you if you reference a newer version of commons-io in the main build script. If the robospice jar only referenced commons-io, but didn't package it up, then you would *have* to declare it as a dependency in your main script in order for your project to build.

Comment: I've added commons-io:commons-io:2.4 to dependency list. I just wondering why -q dependency above shows that org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2 replaced but it its not.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The more I hear about Gradle the less I like it. Sounds very hard to use with some pretty bad defaults.